# Auto-load Grafana dashboard from public dashboards directory

Tags: grafana

in the *infrastructure-as-code* way I'd like to automate provisioning of a Grafana instance pre-loaded with certain dashboards from the [public Grafana Dashboards directory](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards).

I'm aware of the way to pre-load Grafana with a dashboard in the `.json` format, but not via the unique dashboard ID reference that identifies the desired dashboard from the portal mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use Dashboard ID 11568 as an example:

Step 1: Download the .json

> curl https://grafana.com/api/dashboards/11568/revisions/1/download -o ~/Desktop/dashboard.json

Step 2: Embed the .json into a configmap & label it so the grafana dashboard sidecar container will auto load it.

> kubectl create configmap mydashboard --from-file=$HOME/Desktop/dashboard.json -n=monitoring --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl label -f - --dry-run=client -o yaml --local grafana_dashboard=1 > ~/Desktop/dashboard.yaml

Step 3: Wrap the configmap in gitops Custom Resources Flux v2 CD as example

```
cp ~/Desktop/dashboard.yaml  ~/Desktop/gitrepo/base/dashboard.yaml


temp="""
resources:
- dashboard.yaml
"""
echo "$temp" | tee ~/Desktop/gitrepo/base/kustomization.yaml


temp="""
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
  name: gitrepo
spec: 
  gitImplementation: go-git
  ref:
    branch: master
url: https://somegitrepo.com/somepath
---
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: gitops-deployment
spec:
  interval: 1m
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: gitrepo
  path: ./base
"""
echo "$temp" | tee -a ~/Desktop/gitrepo/deploy.yaml
```

The above pseudo code means that if you did

> kubectl apply -f ~/Desktop/gitrepo/deploy.yaml

A flux gitrepository CR would be created with a kustomization CR that references it, FluxCD's Kustomization Controller would do the equivalent of:

> cd ~/Desktop/gitrepo/base && kustomize build . && kubectl apply -f -

so it'd basically do a gitops kustomization based deployment of configmap that has a grafana dashboard.json embedded inside, and is in the correct namespace with the correct label such that grafana installed with prometheus operator (the version of grafana with the sidecar that auto loads dashboards), would auto load it "in the *infrastructure-as-code* way"

Answer (score 0):

Grafana can downloads those dashboards (of course it needs access to the internet). Example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jq --version >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require jq but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
### Please edit grafana_* variables to match your Grafana setup:
grafana_host="http://localhost:3000"
grafana_cred="admin:admin"
# Keep grafana_folder empty for adding the dashboards in "General" folder
grafana_folder="AWS CloudWatch"
ds=(1516 677 139 674 590 659 758 623 617 551 653 969 650 644 607 593 707 575 1519 581 584 2969 8050 11099 11154 11155 12979 13018 13040 13104);
folderId=$(curl -s -k -u "$grafana_cred" $grafana_host/api/folders | jq -r --arg grafana_folder  "$grafana_folder" '.[] | select(.title==$grafana_folder).id')
if [ -z "$folderId" ] ; then echo "Didn't get folderId" ; else echo "Got folderId $folderId" ; fi
for d in "${ds[@]}"; do
  echo -n "Processing $d: "
  j=$(curl -s -k -u "$grafana_cred" $grafana_host/api/gnet/dashboards/$d | jq .json)
  payload="{\"dashboard\":$j,\"overwrite\":true"
  if [ ! -z "$folderId" ] ; then payload="${payload}, \"folderId\": $folderId }";  else payload="${payload} }" ; fi
  curl -s -k -u "$grafana_cred" -XPOST -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "$payload" \
    $grafana_host/api/dashboards/import; echo ""
done
```

Source: https://github.com/monitoringartist/grafana-aws-cloudwatch-dashboards

Feel free to modify it for your favorite language and desired set of dashboards. Keep in mind that some dashboards may need also input variable(s).